# I want to skip the item if it doesn't exist appium java

Tags: appium

I have the following item

```
MobileElement el2 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("New Account");
    el2.click();
```

If the item exists, I want to click
If it is not available, I want to exit the program

driver.closeApp();

Comment: Writing a first well-received question is hard. So when posting questions on SO you should try to show the readers what you already did to solve the problem. Merely stating "help me with this" will probably not contribute to the willingness of user to help you. In addition, you should better explain, what exactly is not working (e.g. what happens with your code quoted when you click; is it called at all? and so forth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can do it with try/catch thing.

```
try{
   MobileElement el2 = (MobileElement)driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("New Account");
   el2.click();
    }
catch{
     driver.closeApp();
    }
```

Comment: try{
   MobileElement el2 = (MobileElement)driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("New Account");
   el2.click();
    }
catch(Exception exp){
     driver.closeApp();
    }